# How to execute a program periodically? & disply difeerence in output

Tags: command-line, execute-command

I want to **run command repeatedly and display their output**.

Example:

I want to run `ls` command repeatedly and display output **so-that I can see changes in directory contents.**

Also facility to **highlight difference** in out-put and specify **time-interval**.

How to do that? suggest command.